# C++ missing Header files

Tags: c++, ide, header-files, turbo-c++

I recently installed **Turbo C++** from the official page, and installed it.
But after running it, I found that it was missing many header files (like **iostream**, **iomanip**, **graphics**, **conio**, etc..). The only header files available were **stdio.h** and **math.h**. I want the other header files, because I am trying for creating a project of structure of an atom using **graphics**, and I need other headers too for **I/O operations**.

**From where can I get these header files? Please help.**

Comment: `I recently installed Turbo C++` - please do yourself a favor, upload it back, and install a C++ compiler.

Comment: What made you choose that? There are modern compilers available out there.

Comment: Modern compilers for free, no less.

Comment: Turbo C++ is OLD.  Use a modern C++ compiler - g++, clang, an up-to-date Visual C++, even Embarcadero's latest C++Builder, etc.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Idk which one to use for C++ development purpose. Can you suggest? I have Visual Studio 12, but the C++ files it contains are corrupted due to a virus many months ago, I removed/cleaned the virus, but It has some affected places in my hard drive. I don't have VS12 installer, so I am not able to repair it. It works fine for other langs.

Comment: This could be a start: http://www.stroustrup.com/compilers.html The list is old but you should find one that works on it.

Comment: If you want full IDE then there's visual studio 17 which is free, but it's big. You can always just download clang a use any text editor or Vim.

Comment: @SaumitraTopinkatti _"but the C++ files it contains are corrupted due to a virus many months ago,"_ Aaahrgh! What's that?? Setup a clean development environment to develop code in 1st place.

Comment: Not to mention that the [c++ tag wiki info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info) already mentions the compilers and IDE's preferrably to use modern c++ standards.

Comment: The official page for TurboC++ probably never existed, commercial Internet was in its infancy,  or vanished with the rest of official Turbo C++ support back in the mid 1990s. UNLESS you are talking the 2006 release of TurboC++ which is a very, very different beast from the 1990s TurboC++.

Comment: @user4581301 ok np I am downloading Visual studio 17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turbo C++ is a compiler/IDE for Borland C++, a dialect of pre-standard C++.

After ISO C++98 ... well, a lot of stuff happened over the intervening two decades.

What you want is one of the modern compilers compliant with at least ISO C++98, but preferably ISO C++11 or ISO C++14.

In a short, not fully inclusive list:
Microsoft Visual Compiler (MSVC), Intel C++ Compiler (ICC), Gnu Compiler Collection (GCC), and LLVM Clang ones I can think of off the top of my head.

There's a number of IDEs, but Eclipse, Code::Blocks, and Visual Studio Code are reasonably popular, and, probably importantly, free.

Comment: Sooo, do I need Microsoft Visual Compiler? Or shall I reinstall Visual Studio?

Comment: @SaumitraTopinkatti Visual Compiler comes with Visual Studio. The standard library headers are compiler specific, as they link to the standard library binaries included with the compiler. I'd recommend a suggestion from elsewhere: install Visual Studio 17 if you can.